# Modal Bottom Sheet and Bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I get the following error when I run code similar to the below code: BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc.

To replicate

```
BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => getIt<TheBloc>()
          child: BlocBuilder<TheBloc, TheState>(
          build: (context, state) =>
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () => _showModal(context),
            child: const Text('SHOW BLOC MODAL'),
),
```

...

```
void _showModal(BuildContext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
          return MaterialButton(
               onPressed() {
                       context.bloc<TheBloc>().add(
                         TheEvent.someEvent(),
                       );
               }
              child: Text('Press button to add event to bloc')
          );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: I reviewed you snippets - this example should work. I guess reason somewhere in you real code

Comment: @SergeySalnikov the issue was this code, I fixed it by wrapping the builder of the modal in a BlocProvider.value as per the bloc api reference. I've added the answer to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to wrap the builder of showModalBottomSheet with a BlocProvider.value as follows:
As the context is new.

```
return BlocProvider.value(
     value: BlocProvider.of<TheBloc>(context),
     child: MaterialButton( ...
     ...
```

Comment: It will more clear if you pass bloc to `_showModal(TheBloc bloc)` and skip unnessesssary lookup in context =)

Comment: can u please explain it little bit more

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you need this bloc only in bottom sheet and nowhere else, the better and cleaner solution is create the StatefullWidget for bottom sheet content, create the Bloc inside this widget in `initState()` work with bloc in `build()` method and free resources in `dispose()` method.

```
  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
          return MyBottomSheet(); // your stateful widget
        );
    },
  );
```

Using bloc like above guarantee that state of your bloc will be the same on each `showModalBottomSheet` call

Note. If you need to preserve state of bloc, you can try to use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` (did not tested)